# JWT in localStorage only works after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular, jwt, angular-local-storage

So I am working on an angular2 application and am trying to generate a JWT after logging in so that a user's profile information can be obtained. I can successfully login and that's when I generate the token. After logging in I route the user to the profile page and that's where I call my api to get the user information. All of this only works after I login and refresh to page.

```
this.auth_service
      .Login(this.email, this.password)
      .subscribe(
              data => {
                         this.global_events.change_nav_bar.emit(true)
                         console.log('logged in successfully: ' + data)
                         this.router.navigate(['/profile'])
                     })
```

// auth_service above calls this method

```
Login(email, password): Observable<boolean>
    {
        return this.http
                    .post('/api/login', JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password}), this.Get_Headers('no_auth'))
                    .map(Handle_Response)

        function Handle_Response(response: Response)
        {
            let token = response.json() && response.json().token
            if(token)
            {
                this.token = token
                localStorage.setItem('current_user', JSON.stringify({ email: email, token: token }))
                return true
            }
            else
                return false
        }
    }
```

// Then in my profile component I do this. I have experimented with different timeout times.

```
ngOnInit(): void
    {
        this.global_events.change_nav_bar.emit(true)

        setTimeout(() => this.Get_User_Data(), 10000)
    }
```

Comment: code looks good, are you getting any error? token is stored in local storage have you checked it? what is get_User_data() function is doing is looking for local storage?

Comment: this.Get_User_Data() is calling my api/profile which uses the jwt to access the route "router.get('/api/profile', auth, Get_User)". The error I get is a 401 unauthorized error when I call the this.Get_User_Data(). What do you mean by is the token stored in localStorage? I mean it has to be if it works on refresh right?

Comment: 401 error means the user is not authorized, user is when authorized that u r not passing auth token in that api request. make sure that u r getting token in that get_user_data() method and you are sending it with request. otherwise you wan't get 401 error.

Comment: Here is how I am sending the token for the request, once again, works after refreshing the page but not the first time, options = {headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token}},                        this.http.get('/api/profile/', options)
             .map((res: Response) => res.json())

Comment: this looks fine, but problem is that "/profile" at that time its not working and after refreshing its working. that means when u redirect use at that time it unable to find token and and its not sending token that is why u r getting 401. to debug this fir login and when u redirect user to /profile page put console.log with in ngOnit() and also put console log with in get_user_data() where u taking token from  localstorage. make sure you are getting token in console.log() this can help me to debug.

Comment: I tried setting another random public variable in the auth_service and then initialize it inside the Login() method of auth_service. It is also returning undefined. So the problem is not the toke per say but just the way I am doing all the asynchronous calls. When I use auth_service inside the profile component, it's variables haven't been initialized yet for some reason, event though i am initializing them inside the Login() method.

Comment: please look at this line: "let token = response.json() && response.json().token". just try response.json().token || false. then try to look that value of token is set of not. if you provide me plunker code than i will help you to solve your error fast.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this (not really solved but found another solution) by just pulling the token directly from localStorage instead of setting in the authenticationService